# multi-layer grayscale input in u-net

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I have successfully trained a u-net for the specific task of cell segmentation using `(256, 256, 1)` grayscale input and `(256, 256, 1)` binary label. I used zhixuhao's unet implemention in Keras (git rep. [here](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet)).What I am trying to do now is to train the same model using multiple grayscale layer as input.

To make things easier, let's assume I want to use 2 grayscale image `im1` and `im2`, each of size `(256, 256, 1)`. Label `Y` is the same for `im1` and `im2`. I want to feed the model an input of size `(256, 256, 2)`, where the first component of the 3rd axis is `im1` and the second one is `im2`.

To that end, I changed the train data generator to :

```
def MultipleInputGenerator(train_path, sub_path_1, sub_path_2, image_folder='images', mask_folder='masks', batch_size, aug_dict, images_color_mode='grayscale', masks_color_mode='grayscale',
            flag_multi_class=False, num_class=2, target_size=(256,256), seed=1):

    # Keras generator
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)

    # Multiple input data augmentation
    image_generator_1 = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            sub_path_1,
            classes = [image_folder],
            class_mode = None,
            color_mode = images_color_mode,
            target_size = target_size,
            batch_size = batch_size,
            seed = seed)

    image_generator_2 = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            sub_path_2,
            classes = [image_folder],
            class_mode = None,
            color_mode = images_color_mode,
            target_size = target_size,
            batch_size = batch_size,
            save_to_dir = save_to_dir,
            save_prefix  = image_save_prefix,
            seed = seed)

    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_path,
            classes = [mask_folder],
            class_mode = None,
            color_mode = masks_color_mode,
            target_size = target_size,
            batch_size = batch_size,
            save_to_dir = save_to_dir,
            save_prefix  = mask_save_prefix,
            seed = seed)

    train_generator = zip(image_generator_1, image_generator_2, mask_generator)

    for (img1, img2, mask) in train_generator:
        img1, mask1 = adjustData(img1, mask, flag_multi_class, num_class)
        img2, mask2 = adjustData(img2, mask, flag_multi_class, num_class)
        yield (np.stack((img1, img2), axis=0), mask1)
```

with `adjustData` being an auxillary function which normalises the arrays from [0, 255] to [0, 1]

As you can see, I've tried to stack grayscale arrays in a single input. 
When creating the unet model, I changed the input size from `(256, 256, 1)` to `(256, 256, 2)` :

```
train_gen = MultipleInputGenerator(train_folder, sub_path_1, sub_path_2, batch_size, aug_dict=data_gen_args)
model = unet(input_size=(256,256,2))
model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, epochs=epochs)
```

Yet, when lauching the command : `python3 main.py`, it starts loading the data correctly but then fails to train the model :

```
Found 224 images belonging to 1 classes.
Epoch 1/2
Found 224 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 224 images belonging to 1 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 50, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, epochs=epochs)
  File "*/virtenv/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "*/virtenv/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "*/virtenv/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 220, in fit_generator
    reset_metrics=False)
  File "*/virtenv/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1508, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "*/virtenv/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "*/virtenv/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 32, 256, 256, 1)
```

with 32 being the batch_size.

Has anyone already managed to train a unet (or any other CNN) with multi-layer input other than RGB images ? Or does anyone have an idea of how I could get thing working ?

Thanks.

Comment: As the defined im2 as (256, 256, 2), do you mean by multimodal image?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood your question. I had access to multiple grey images of the same picture, each of them highlighting different elements from the original picture (e.g. if the original picture was composed of a group of people: then I could possibly consider 4 grey images: 1- one with all the people wearing pants, 2- one with all the people wearing shorts, 3- one with all the people wearing tees, 4- one with all the people wearing hats). I wanted to stack these multiple 2D images into a single 3D input.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected input shape is `(32, 256, 256, 2)` whereas the output shape of your generator is `(2, 32, 256, 256, 1)`. It's because `np.stack` is adding one additional dimension than the input arrays. You can solve this by using `np.concatenate` instead of `np.stack` in your `train_generator` [last line of code block] like following:

```
yield (np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=-1), mask1)
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer! I managed to get things working with a similar approach (i used np.squeeze after np.stack), I will write the final version of my code below.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @bit01, `np.stack` is adding one additional dimension than the input arrays! To get things working I edited the last line of the `MultipleInputTrainGenerator` function as below :

```
img = np.squeeze(np.stack((img1, img2), axis=3), axis=4)
yield (img, mask1)
```

It should work to with `np.concatenate` too but I didn't try it out.